# Parsing a JSON and handling error response from API in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift. I have a BackendProvider with handles the communication with my API. I want to have a config file sync so that I can retrieve some parameters dynamically. I have a fallback case with a local stored JSON file that I can to access in case my API is not reachable or my JSON parsing fails:

> **ConfigFileBackendService**

```
open func getLatestConfig() -> Observable<ConfigFile?> {            
        let urlString = IoC.urlProviderService.getConfigFileUrl()?.absoluteString ?? ""
        let configFileJSONData = IoC.backendCommunicationService.getJsonData(url: urlString)

        return configFileJSONData.map { data in
            if let configFile = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ConfigFile.self, from: data) {
                return configFile
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
```

> **ConfigFileProcessService**

This is the one that falls back to the local stored file:

```
func getConfigFile() -> Observable<ConfigFile> {
        return IoC.configFileBackendService.getLatestConfig()
            .map { configFile in
                guard let configFile = configFile else { fatalError() }
                return configFile
            }
            .catchError { error in
                // Use default config
                let localURL = IoC.urlProviderService.getLocalConfigFileUrl()
                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: localURL)
                    let configFile = try JSONDecoder().decode(ConfigFile.self, from: data)
                    return Observable.just(configFile)
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Error loading local config")
                }
        }
    }
```

This approach works, but I'm having doubts with the `.map` / `.catchError` blocks. Is there a better way to handle the error case? Maybe should I go with, `onNext` and then `onError`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create a custom Observable using `Observable.create()`  to return ConfigFile, if you subscribe using onNext and onError. But this is the regular approach I use in projects.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Daniel T. approach, I got rid of `nil` and made the code crash only if the local config file loading process fails:

```
open class ConfigFileBackendService: ConfigFileBackendServiceProtocol {
    open func getLatestConfig() -> Observable<ConfigFile> {
        let urlString = IoC.urlProviderService.getConfigFileUrl()
        let configFileJSONData = IoC.backendCommunicationService.getJsonData(url: urlString)

        return configFileJSONData.map { try JSONDecoder().decode(ConfigFile.self, from: $0) }
    }
}

class ConfigFileProcessService: ConfigFileProcessServiceProtocol {
    func getConfigFile() -> Observable<ConfigFile> {
        return IoC.configFileBackendService.getLatestConfig()
            .catchError { [weak self] error in
                // Load local config file
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
                guard let strongSelf = self else { fatalError() }
                return Observable.just(strongSelf.getLocalFile())
        }

    }

    private func getLocalFile() -> ConfigFile {
        let localURL = IoC.urlProviderService.getLocalConfigFileUrl()
        guard
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: localURL),
            let configFile = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ConfigFile.self, from: data)
            else { fatalError("Error loading local config") }
        return configFile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks good except for the multiple approaches to handling errors. In one case you use a `try?` and another uses `do... catch` and presumably your `getJsonData(url:)` can emit an Observable error. You are all over the place. I suggest you pick one error handling system and stick to it. The most flexible one is `Event.error`. So something like this:

```
func getLatestConfig() -> Observable<ConfigFile> {
    let urlString = IoC.urlProviderService.getConfigFileUrl()?.absoluteString ?? ""
    let configFileJSONData = IoC.backendCommunicationService.getJsonData(url: urlString)
    return configFileJSONData.map { try JSONDecoder().decode(ConfigFile.self, from: $0) }
}
```

Note that I'm just letting decoding errors route into an Observable error event. No need to deal with `nil` that way.

```
func getConfigFile() -> Observable<ConfigFile> {
    return IoC.configFileBackendService.getLatestConfig()
        .catchError { _ in
            let localURL = IoC.urlProviderService.getLocalConfigFileUrl()
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: localURL)
            let configFile = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ConfigFile.self, from: data)
            return Observable.just(configFile)
        }
}
```

Since you are crashing if either try fails anyway, just put a `!` on them. It has the same effect. You should consider putting the error block into a separate, testable, function because there's no guarantee you are going to hit it during a regular run of the program and it could be broken without you ever realizing it.

Lastly, with the above there is no reason to provide an `onError:` handler in a subscribe because the `getConfigFile()` observable will never emit an error. You might want to have the function return a Driver instead to make the fact more explicit.

Comment: Great explanation! Is it ok to use *force* `try`? I have `swiftlint` on my project and it screams about that. I broke it down into two functions: (see answer below)

Comment: SwiftLint is complaining because your program could crash if the file doesn't exist or if it couldn't decode properly. The thing is, you _want_ the program to crash in those cases (or at least, I assume you want it to because you put a `fatalError()` in the catch.) If you just remove the `!`s then SwiftLint will be happy.